# Conflict of tenses here?

Tags: tense

When I wake up in the morning
I heard her call my name

This extract is from the velvet underground song called"I heard her call my name". I know that when you write songs you have licence to break grammmar. Past simple is for something in the past that won't happen anymore and   "when I wake up " means everytime so it is present. Here there is a conflict between tenses isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

The song is a song, there are two interwoven structures almost as if two people are speaking at once.

> **I know that she cares about me**
> I heard her call my name
> **And I know that she's long dead and gone**
> Still she ain't the same
> **When I wake up in the morning**
> I heard her call my name
> **I know that she's gone, gone, gone**
> I heard her call my name
> **And then my mind split open...**

You should read the bold lines as one narrative, and the other lines as a repetitive refrain and not part of the grammar of the song.

Comment: I've been a fan for 50 years, and still people listen to this group.

Comment: Yes,  I don't normally do "lyrics" questions... but this is the Velvet Underground!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, in songs/poetry, you can break the rules of grammar.

That may have happened here, or someone may have incorrectly transcribed what they thought they heard.

In normal English, the sentence is unequivocally wrong.

Either:

*When I wake up in the morning, I hear her call my name*

or

*When I woke up in the morning, I heard her call my name*

are correct.